# C program to add 2 polynomials and then displaying it

Tags: c

I am writing a C program to add 2 polynomials given by user then displaying it in a separate function but it is not adding anything. In fact, it is not giving any type of error message so I am very confused. I think the mistake can be in 'addpoly' function or display function. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any type of help will be appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 3
struct polynomial
{
    int coeff;
    int exp;
    struct polynomial *next;
};
typedef struct polynomial polynomial;
polynomial *p1=NULL,*p2=NULL,*p3=NULL, *head_address=NULL;



polynomial* create()
{
polynomial *head_address=NULL, *prev_address=NULL, *new_address=NULL;


int i;
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{
    new_address=(polynomial*)malloc(sizeof(polynomial));
    printf("Enter coeff:\n");
    scanf("%d",&new_address->coeff);
    printf("Enter exp:\n");
    scanf("%d",&new_address->exp );
    new_address->next=0;
    if(head_address==NULL){
        head_address=prev_address=new_address;
    }
    else{
        prev_address->next=new_address;
        prev_address=new_address;
    }}
    return head_address; }

void polyadd(polynomial *p1, polynomial *p2,polynomial *p3)
{
     //polynomial* p3=NULL;


    while(p1->next!=NULL && p2->next!=NULL){

        if(p1->exp > p2->exp){
            p3->coeff=p1->coeff;
            p3->exp=p1->exp;
            p1=p1->next;
        }
        else if(p1->exp < p2->exp){
            p3->coeff=p2->coeff;
            p3->exp=p2->exp;
            p2=p2->next;
        }
        else if(p1->exp==p2->exp){
            p3->coeff=p1->coeff + p2->coeff;
            p3->exp=p1->exp;
            p1=p1->next;
            p2=p2->next;
        }


    p3->next=(polynomial*)malloc(sizeof(polynomial));
    p3=p3->next;
    p3->next=NULL; }
    while(p1->next || p2->next){
        if(p1->next){
           p3->exp=p1->exp;
           p3->coeff=p1->coeff;
           p1=p1->next;
        }
        else if(p2->next){
            p3->exp=p2->exp;
            p3->coeff=p2->coeff;
            p2=p2->next;
        }
    p3->next=(polynomial*)malloc(sizeof(polynomial));
    p3=p3->next;
    p3->next=NULL;
    }



}
void display(polynomial *temp){
polynomial *p3;
p3=temp;

temp=head_address;
while(temp->next!=NULL)
    printf("%dx^%d",temp->coeff,temp->exp);
    temp=temp->next;
    if(temp->next!=NULL){
        printf(" + ");
    }

}





int main(){

 polynomial *p1,*p2,*p3;
p1=create();
printf("Next:\n");
p2=create();
polyadd(p1,p2,p3);

printf("Result:\n");
display(p3);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks like a memory reference error.  In your `polyadd()` function you're not mallocing as much as you need to.  Your base `p3` pointer for your linked list is still unallocated when you start referencing off it in your first while loop.  To fix your memory issue you'll want to malloc `p3` before using it and then make sure the subsequent `->next` instances all get malloced before being used.

I don't think this is causing you issues currently but you also have global variables defined at the top and then defined again in `main()`.  The local variables will be the only ones used as long as they're present but I would delete your globals and make sure you don't have unused duplicates to avoid confusion.